# ZoneId and LocalDateTime

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, date

I am running this piece of code in Paris right now, where its 12:40, where ECT = ECT - Europe/Paris

```
LocalDateTime creationDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC());      
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of(ZoneId.SHORT_IDS.get("ECT"));


System.out.println ("creationDateTime --------------------------> " + creationDateTime);        
System.out.println ("creationDateTime.atZone(zone).getHour() ---> " + creationDateTime.atZone(zone).getHour());
System.out.println ("creationDateTime.atZone(zone).getMinute() -> " + creationDateTime.atZone(zone).getMinute());
```

But i am getting this at the console

```
creationDateTime --------------------------> 2017-05-16T10:40:07.882
creationDateTime.atZone(zone).getHour() ---> 10
creationDateTime.atZone(zone).getMinute() -> 40
```

Shouldn't I get 12:40 ???????

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you shouldn't. You've asked for a `ZonedDateTime` with the same `LocalDateTime` that you started with, but associated with a particular time zone.

From the docs for [`LocalDateTime.atZone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-):

> This returns a ZonedDateTime formed from this date-time at the specified time-zone. The result will match this date-time as closely as possible. Time-zone rules, such as daylight savings, mean that not every local date-time is valid for the specified zone, thus the local date-time may be adjusted.

In this case there's no need for adjustment, because 2017-05-16T10:40:07.882 *did* occur in Paris.

It sounds like your mistake was creating a `LocalDateTime` at all. You've basically said "Find out what the current time is in UTC, then take the same *local date and time*, but pretend it's in a different time zone."

If your aim is to get the current time in `zone`, you shouldn't have a `LocalDateTime` at all. Just use:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedNow = ZonedDateTime.now(Clock.system(zone));
```

or (equivalently)

```
ZonedDateTime zonedNow = Clock.systemUTC().instant().atZone(zone);
```

Answer (score 0):

This method returns a `ZonedDateTime`, not a modified `LocalDateTime`. So in this case it will return a `ZonedDateTime` that represents 2017-05-16 10:40 in timezone ETC.